# A better way to check if GET isset and set variable?

Tags: php

Hello I'm having trouble thinking of a way to set custom variables with there `$_GET` counterpart in a cleaner way than below, this is a post-back for the url `http://example.com/postback.php?id={offer_id}&offer={offer_name}&session={session_ip}&payout={payout}` after running I get all `$_GET` with either their data or nil for all variables: `$id`, `$offer`, `$session`, `$payout` obviously i am a php newbie, please go easy on me! Thanks, any help would be great.

```
if (s('id')) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
} else {
    $id = 'nil';
}

if (s('offer')) {
    $offer = $_GET["offer"];
} else {
    $offer = 'nil';
}

if (s('session')) {
    $session = $_GET["session"];
} else {
    $session = 'nil';
}

if (s('payout')) {
    $payout = $_GET["payout"];
} else {
    $payout = 'nil';
}

function s($name) {
   if(isset($_GET["$name"]) && !empty($_GET["$name"])) {
       return true;
   } 
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You can loop through the full `GET`, something like `foreach($_GET as $name => $value)`. `$name` will be the index. With this approach you should initialize all variables first as empty (or `nil`)..

Answer (score 1):

Use extract: http://php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php

```
// Assuming $_GET = array('id' => 123, etc.)
extract($_GET);
var_dump($id);

// And later in your code
if (isset($id)) {
   // Do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a *universal* wrapper

```
<?php 
     function getValue($key, $fallback='nil') {
         if(isset($_GET[$key]) $val = trim($_GET[$key]);
         else $val = null;
         return ($val) ? $val : $fallback;
     }
```

and then you can handle it easyer by

```
     <?php 
            $id = getValue('id'); ...
```

Comment: Is there a way it can work out the variables via the url (parse)?

Comment: @Benjamin is the data in `GET` or is the URL a string?

Answer (score 0):

`isset` is not needed, and maybe you can use the ternary operator.

```
$id = !empty($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : null;
$offer = !empty($_GET["offer"]) ? $_GET["offer"] : null;
$session = !empty($_GET["session"]) ? $_GET["session"] : null;
$payout = !empty($_GET["payout"]) ? $_GET["payout"] : null;
```